# How can i replace or remove red play button on YouTube Iframe API?

Tags: iframe, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

How can i replace or remove **red play button** on YouTube Iframe API? I'm trying to hide it but can't find solution.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post your work-in-progress implementation.

Comment: I've tried to replace the css with my local styling or using jquery to overwrite styling. Neiither doesn't work well.